# Added event color error PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm doing event calendar project which involves two basic panels:

1. Admin panel
2. Member panel

About this specific case:

When one member adds event the date, on which event is added, changes color to red (when there is not event, it is blank). So the problem is that when I enter as other member the date, which was previously added as previously logged in user, is still colored red, but it's not showing the event. The aim of this would be that it must be no color on other user's calendar date in case that user didn't added event on that date by himself. Here's the code with some comments of understanding.

```
$dateToCompare = $monthstring. '/' . $daystring. '/' . $year;

//$monthstring, $daystring and $year are just the date.
$sqlCount = "select * from eventcalendar where eventDate='".$dateToCompare."'";
$noOfEvent = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sqlCount));

if($noOfEvent >= 1 ){
    //Bootstrap class of red color for <td> section of current date
    echo "class='alert alert-danger'";  
}
```

Here's also a picture of eventcalendar table in my MySQL database.
[image]

Every event is stored in same table, but it's decelared as users id in which users calendar event would be showed. How to do it for the color, what do I must do in database solve this problem?

Comment: Its inside the TD? echo "class='alert alert-danger'";

Comment: yeah yeah, it's not problem in html or the code, I just need something to put in database to and add it code and solve, but I'm beginner programmer and I don't know the way to do it xD

Comment: Suppose to be if $noOfEvent > 0 add red color in database right??

Comment: $noOfEvent is number of events added in database table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but what I understand you want to show events with red color but only those which added by the current user. But when you get noOfEvent for the specified data your only write the date itself. And when the query runs it's gives you the numbers of events added for that data regardless of the user id. So as simple as that just like this :

```
$sqlCount = "SELECT * FROM `eventcalendar` WHERE `eventDate`='".$dateToCompare."' AND `user_id` = '*current user id*'";
```

And in that case if the event added by a different user it remains blank for the current user.

Comment: That is what I've been asking for. Thanks mate :)